# Seperation of files from one folder to another based on their filenames

Tags: python

My filenames have pattern like 29_11_2019_17_05_17_1050_R__2.png and 29_11_2019_17_05_17_1550_2
I want to write a function which separates these files and puts them in different folders.
Please find my code below but its not working.
Can you help me with this?

```
def sort_photos(folder, dir_name):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    
        wavelengths = ["1550_R_", "1550_", "1050_R_", "1200_"]
        for x in wavelengths:
            if x == "1550_R_":
                if re.match(r'.*x.*', filename):
                    filesrc = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    
                    shutil.copy(filesrc, dir_name)
                    print("Filename has 'x' in it, do something")
    
                    print("file 1550_R_ copied")
            # cv2.imwrite(dir_name,filename)
            else:
                print("filename doesn't have '1550_R_' in it (so maybe it only has 'N' in it)")
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you include the error you get? Which OS that you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

In order to construct a RegEx using a variable, you can use string-interpolation.

In Python3.6+, you can use f-strings to accomplish this. In this case, the condition for your second `if` statement could be:

```
if re.match(fr'.*{x}.*', filename) is not None:
```

instead of:

```
if re.match(r'.*x.*', filename) is not None:
```

Which would only ever match filenames with an 'x' in them. I think is the immediate (though not necessarily only) problem in your example code.

**Footnote**

Earlier versions of Python do string interpolation differently, the oldest (AFAIK) is %-formatting, e.g:

```
if re.match(r".*%s.*" % x, filename) is not None:
```

Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very cleared about which problem you encounter.
However, there are two suggestions:

1. To detect character x in file name, you can just use:

   ```
   if('x' in filename):
       ...
   ```
2. If you only intended to move the files, a file check should be added:

   ```
   if os.path.isfile(name):
       ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have much time so I've edited your function which acts very close to what you wanted. It essentially reads file names, and copies them to separate directories but in directories named by wavelengths instead.  Though currently it cannot differentiate between `'1550_'` and `'1550_R_'` since `'1550_R_'` includes `'1550_'` and I didn't have much time. You can create a conditional statement for it by a few lines and there you go. (If you do not do that it will create two directories `'1550_'` and `'1550_R_'` but it will copy files that are eligible for either to both of the folders.)

One final note that as I said that I didn't have much time I've made it all simpler that the destination folders are created just where your files are located. You can add it easily if you want by a few lines too.

```
import cv2
import os
import re
import shutil

def sort_photos(folder):
    wavelengths = ["1550_R_", "1550_", "1050_R_", "1200_"]
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        for x,idx in zip(wavelengths, range(len(wavelengths))):
            if (x in filename):
                filesrc = os.path.join(folder, filename)
                path = './'+x+'/'
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    os.mkdir(path)
                shutil.copy(filesrc, path+filename)
        #           print("Filename has 'x' in it, do something")

            # cv2.imwrite(dir_name,filename)
#             else:
#                 print("filename doesn't have 'A' in it (so maybe it only has 'N' in it)") 
                

########## USAGE: sort_photos(folder), for example, go to the folder where all the files are located:

sort_photos('./')
```